# Angular component controller injection issue

Tags: angularjs

Angular 1.5 introduced [components](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component) (*special kind of directive*)

For directive we can write:

```
app.directive('myDirective',
            ['$timeout','$mdToast','$rootScope',  // <-- injection
            function ($timeout, $mdToast,$rootScope) {
return {
   link: {},
    //...
        }
    }
```

How can we write injection for components?

For sure I can write, something like:

```
app.component('myComponent',  {
            restrict: 'E',
            bindings: {
                data: '='
            },
            templateUrl: 'template.html',
            controllerAs: 'vm',
            controller: 'myComponentCtrl'
    });
```

and:

```
app.controller('myComponentCtrl', 
    ['$scope',  '$timeout', 
     function ($scope, $timeout) {
   // ....
}]);
```

But I want to write *build-in* controller, like:

```
app.component('myComponentCtrl', {
  templateUrl: 'template.html',
  controller: function($scope, $timeout) {
    //...
  }
});
```

Above mentioned style minifying (GRUNT) will brake my code `Unknown provider: aProvider <- a`,

So **how to write properly injection for components?**

Any ideas?

The demo I use <kbd>[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ik9IvgHDpdTfa3kA2mag?p=preview)</kbd>

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to wrap `controller: function($scope, $timeout) {` in the minification syntax.

I'm actually not a fan of the inline but :

```
app.component('myComponentCtrl', {
 templateUrl: 'template.html',
 controller: ['$scope', '$timeout', function($scope, $timeout) {
  //...
 }]
});
```

Cleaner form:

```
app.component('myComponentCtrl', {
 templateUrl: 'template.html',
 controller: myComponentCtrl
})


myComponentCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', '$timeout'];
/* @ngInject */
function myComponentCtrl($scope, $timeout) {
  //...

}
```

Third option is to use ng-annotate and you can remove the `myComponentCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', '$timeout'];` line above.

Comment: yes, 1st option is pretty ugly form, agree with `ng-annotate`.

Comment: I like the cleaner example but I can not comprehend it. How come you set the $inject property on myComponentCtrl before actually creating the object ? Also you are asigning the controller to a component declared before actually declaring the controller function. How will that work ? I think something is missing from the cleaner example.

Comment: @Liviu Google "javascript hoisting". TL;DR: JavaScript var and function declarations are "hoisted" to the top of the scope, so you can declare a function anywhere in your code and access it the same way as if you had declared it right up at the beginning of the current scope.

Answer (score 4):

You can just go ahead and use the array notation for your controller.

```
app.component('myComponent',  {
    restrict: 'E',
    bindings: {
        data: '='
    },
    templateUrl: 'template.html',
    controllerAs: 'vm',
    controller: ['$scope', function ($scope) {

    }]
});
```

What i prefer to do however is use a tool like [ng-annotate](https://github.com/olov/ng-annotate) on my build pipeline that automatically converts your injectables into array notation, so your source code does not need to worry about that.